# How report scheduling works if the time frame is set to custom. i.e., Last 7 days?

Tags: reporting, schedule

I have scheduled a report so that I should receive email once in a week and with last 7 days data. For that, I have adjusted the Time Frame to Last 7 days. But when I changed it like that, it automatically puts the date range in the two date text boxes which is from and to date ranges.

My question is, having this report in the scheduler, will it send me the report data dynamically for the "last 7 days" or will it send the report data for the date range that has been configured at the first time i.e., for the date ranges given in the screen shot on all the future runs? Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a date range such as "last 7 days", it will automatically update each time the report is run. In other words, it will be the last seven days from the current day. The only time the dates do not change is if you choose Custom; in that case, the dates will remain unchanged as time moves forward. You can also use the date ranges specified in [Relative Date Filter Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5) when referencing date or date/time fields in the custom filters of the report, such as "Created Date equals THIS WEEK" to find all records created since the most recent Sunday.